# Django "This field is required." error every time I fill out my video post form

Tags: django, django-forms

As the title says, I'm getting this error and I'm not really sure why am I getting it.

Here's my models.py for the video upload form:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='videos/thumbnails/', null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/video/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=["mp4", "mov"])])
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user',on_delete=models.PROTECT)    
    description=models.TextField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)], blank=True)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Igdb, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here's my forms.py:

```
class videoupload(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                           widget= forms.TextInput
                           (attrs={'placeholder':'Title'}))
    thumbnail = forms.ImageField()
    video = forms.FileField(widget= forms.FileInput
                           (attrs={'class':'videobox'}))
    description = forms.Textarea()
    category = forms.Select()
    game = forms.Select()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'thumbnail', 'video','category', 'game']
        exclude = ("date","user", "slug")
```

And here's my views.py:

```
def uploadpage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = videoupload(request.POST,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            video = form.save(commit=False)
            video.user = request.user
            video.save()
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = videoupload()
    return render(request, "glavna/upload.html", {"form": form})
```

I've just called {{forms.as_p}} inside html, also I saw that other people added enctype="multipart/form-data". Here's upload.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block css_files %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/base.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'glavna/upload.css'%}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
  <script type="module" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/model-viewer/3.0.1/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'glavna/favicon.ico' %}" type="image/x-icon">
{% endblock css_files %}
{% block title %}
  Početna
{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">
        Upload
      </button>
      {% if form.errors %}
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          {% for field, errors in form.errors.items %}
              <p>{{ field }}: {{ errors }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
  {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm trying to have it post a video, username would be automatically filled out.

Comment: Share your HTML form.

Comment: Alright I added it.

Comment: add an `else` to your `if form.is_valid():` and put `print(form.errors.as_data())` in it. Re-submit, look at terminal output. It *should* show a dictionary and the **key** will be the field it's mad about.

Comment: I got this error django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: glavna_video.user_name_id

Comment: Alright, I fixed it. The problem was that I used OneToOneField in Video model. OneToOneField doesn't allow usernames to be same, it was fixed by replace OneToOneField with ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I fixed it. The problem was that I used OneToOneField in Video model. OneToOneField doesn't allow usernames to be same, it was fixed by replace OneToOneField with ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) is in essence a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) with a [**`unique=True`** constraint [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique), it is a way to model an [*injective function* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). Here it does not make much sense, since that would mean that each person can post *at most* only one `Video`.

That being said, you can further simplify your view to:

```
def uploadpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = videoupload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = videoupload()
    return render(request, 'glavna/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

---

**Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,

> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `VideoUploadForm` instead of
> <s>`videoupload`</s>.

---

**Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

**Note**: You can make use of [**`django-autoslug`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug) to automatically create a slug based on other field(s).